# How to escape backslashes in replacement part of a pattern substitution?

Tags: bash

I would like to replace all slashes `/` in a string with this string:

```
(\/|\/\/)?(\\r)
```

I tried something like that:

```sh
param1=`echo ${string//\//(\/|\/\/)?(\\r)}`
```

And my output is: `(/|//)?(r)`, not `(\/|\/\/)?(\\r)`

So how I can escape my backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution, especially [the notorious backquoted version](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), is redundant there. And the replacement part of the pattern substitution should be quoted as otherwise backslashes are consumed during [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal).

```
$ string=/
$ param1=${string//\//'(\/|\/\/)?(\\r)'}
$ echo "$param1"
(\/|\/\/)?(\\r)
```